# Java parse JSON for android

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse Json for my android app, but I couldn't get it work. I am using org.json library which is port by android. I tried different tutorials but I get and exception called JSONException.

This is the json response I need to parse.

```
{"status":0,"id":"8bb90729f836f30d179689b01f60fb41-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"this is a simple test to see if it's working","confidence":0.88661164}]}
```

And this is the code I use to parse it.

```
public void extractJsonData(String feed){
        feed = feed.trim();
        feed = feed.trim();
        try {
                JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
                Log.i(GetJSon.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("status"));
                Log.i(GetJSon.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("id"));
                Log.i(GetJSon.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("hypotheses"));
                gettting the array of hypotheses
                JSONObject hypotheses = jsonObject.getJSONObject("hypotheses");
                Log.i(GetJSon.class.getName(), hypotheses.getString("utterance"));
                //Log.i(GetJSon.class.getName(), hypotheses.getString("confidence"));
            //}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I get.

```
07-09 15:54:38.564: I/global(8719): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
07-09 15:54:38.564: I/Json Response(8719): {"status":0,"id":"8bb90729f836f30d179689b01f60fb41-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"this is a simple test to see if it's working","confidence":0.88661164}]}
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719): org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["status"] not found.
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:287)
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at com.isuru.recordapp.GetJSon.extractJsonData(GetJSon.java:19)
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at com.isuru.recordapp.Main$7.onClick(Main.java:253)
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-09 15:54:38.564: W/System.err(8719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:54:38.574: W/System.err(8719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 15:54:38.574: W/System.err(8719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-09 15:54:38.574: W/System.err(8719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-09 15:54:38.574: W/System.err(8719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 15:54:38.574: I/NotificationService(57): enqueueToast pkg=com.isuru.recordapp callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@44d97440 duration=1
07-09 15:54:38.644: W/InputManagerService(57): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44e09d28
```

I am trying this since yesterday. But still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();` ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making your life much harder.

```
public void extractJsonData(String feed){         
feed = feed.trim(); 
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(feed);
```

then extract the keyvalue pairs

Answer (score 4):

```
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
```

should be

```
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(feed);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `JSONObject` is empty

```
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
```

You have to pass respose string to `JSONObject`'s constructor like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new empty `JSONObject` that has nothing to do with the `String` you passed in. You need `new JSONObject(feed)`